# DNS load balancing with algorithm

Tags: domain-name-system, load-balancing

I have 2 web servers that I want to load balance between them using the DNS technique.

But the kind of load balancing I want to implement is a little bit different: When a request comes in to the load balance server (Which I'll set up in addition to the 2 other servers), I want the load balancer to go through a short algorithm that I'll wrote - in order to decide to which server he should send the traffic.

Any similar implementation, or examples for general DNS load balancing that I should review? Please, anything will help - preferably examples.

Comment: Depending on what you are doing with those servers, maybe consider a hosted DNS solution that can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find plenty of examples by searching for commercial GSLB documents (from F5, Citrix, Brocade, etc). Don't know what platform you're working on, but you may be able to implement this as a patch to a DNS server software such as bind.

Comment: Sorry for responding late, have been busy at some stuff.  Any chance you'll expand on the BIND thing? (Those GSLB are too pricey for me, so this is my second option.)

Comment: Hah, I thought you were going to write code for it and hence suggested BIND. I don't think there is a BIND plugin / mode that does GSLB (as the DNS purists hate GSLB). You may be find a purely software based GSLB from a commercial LB vendor for cheap / free. I don't want to suggest any, but you'll find it by googling.

Comment: I'll try to check out for a solution with a BIND implementation. I found some great articles explaining it.